# How to add multiple hot spot at the top of panorama in android using PanoramaGL Library?

Tags: android

I am able to load the panorama image using PanoramaGL Library and it is working perfectly. But I am not able to add multiple hot spot even single hot spot on the top of panorama image? can any one please help me for this issue?

Comment: *can any one please help me for this issue?* With what issue? Writing/modifying the code is not an issue.

Comment: @ Selvin how to add the hot spot on the top of panorama?

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into the HelloPanoramaGL example from https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/wiki/UserGuide ? 
in the Mainactivity on line 243 you find the following :

```
panorama.addHotspot(new PLHotspot(1, new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(context, R.raw.hotspot), false), 0.0f, 170.0f, 0.05f, 0.05f));
```

the last 4 parameters define the vertical position, the horizontal position in degrees (Yaw) and the size of the Hotspot image.
Also make sure that the defined image at R.raw.hotspot exists in your raw folder

If you want to add your Hotspots with Json, there are example files for that too for every type of Panorama

hope this gets you going

Comment: How to add hotspot with on Click, because I am unable to get normalized X and normalized Y while calling this function -> plHotspot2.setPosition(normalizedX, normalizedY)